# How to connect 3PL sandbox with Shopify Sandbox

Tags: shopify

We are working on ERP system which will fetch orders from Shopify and fulfilment details from 3PL central. We need assistance on how to connect shopify sandbox with 3PL sandbox.

Thanks,

Comment: You should paste your code / work here to make other aware about where you are facing challenge.

Comment: from my understanding your app will fetch tracking details from 3PL and fulfill orders on the Shopify. so you will need to make use of fulfillment admin API

https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/rest/reference/shipping-and-fulfillment/fulfillment#createV2-2020-01

Comment: Thanks for reply. My need is I have shopify sandbox and 3PL sandbox. I need suggestion how can I connect both to check how orders are passing from shopify to 3PL and rest fulfilment flow.

Comment: are orders already passing to 3PL services ? if no and you need to pass orders then you need to create webhook on shopify with topic => orders/create. this webhook will automaytically give you order data whenever it is created on shopify store in JSON format. now you can pass it to your 3PL sandbox

Comment: Hello Bhargav, Yes orders are already passing to 3PL. shopify and 3PL already communicates with each other. I need help if it is possible with 3PL sandbox(connect 3PL sandbox with shopify sandbox)

Comment: if you are asking about shopify sandbox then you can create your own development store which will work like sandbox. 

Pass order from Shopify to 3PL using Webhooks setup ( that you told already working )

Now you will need to listen for tracking update from 3PL ( or create cron that check  the same ). 

as soon as you get data push it to the shopify using shopify fulfillment Admin API